# How to disable `transform` animation while scrolling with Floating UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, floating-ui

I have a floating menu component which I made using `floating-ui` library. I animate the `transform` property to nicely adjust the position of menu. However, this is a problem while scrolling, wherein I do not want the animation to take effect.

Is it possible to add a class to a floating element only when scrolling to not animate this property in such a case (in React)?

```
import {
  useFloating,
  autoUpdate,
  offset,
  flip,
  shift,
  useClick,
  FloatingFocusManager,
  useTransitionStyles,
  FloatingPortal,
  FloatingArrow,
  useTransitionStatus,
  hide,
  inline,
  useDismiss,
  useInteractions,
} from "@floating-ui/react";
import { arrow } from "@floating-ui/react";

import { Editor, isNodeSelection, posToDOMRect } from "@tiptap/core";
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { AnimatePresence, easeIn, motion } from "framer-motion";
import * as Portal from "@radix-ui/react-portal";

const ARROW_WIDTH = 16;
const ARROW_HEIGHT = 8;
const GAP = 8;

type Props = {
  editor: Editor;
  open: boolean;
  setOpen?: any;
  children: ReactNode;
};

// Adapted from https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/2305#issuecomment-1020665146
export const BubbleMenu = ({ editor, children }: Props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrolling((prev) => true);
      console.log("Calling handle scroll", scrolling);
    };
    const handleScrollEnd = () => {
      setScrolling((prev) => false);
      console.log("Calling handle scroll end", scrolling);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    window.addEventListener("scrollend", handleScrollEnd);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      window.removeEventListener("scrollend", handleScrollEnd);
    };
  });

  // This function determines whether menu should be shown or not
  const shouldShow = (floating) => {
    // selection not empty?
    let notEmpty = !editor.state.selection.empty;
    if (notEmpty && !editor.isFocused) {
      // We want to hide menu when editor loses focus. The only exception is when
      // Floating element has this focus
      const menuFocused = floating?.contains(document.activeElement);
      if (menuFocused) return true;
      return false;
    }

    return notEmpty;
  };

  const arrowRef = useRef(null);
  const {
    floatingStyles,
    refs: { reference, setReference, setFloating },
    elements: { floating },
    middlewareData,
    context,
    placement,
  } = useFloating({
    open,
    onOpenChange: (open, event, reason) => {
      setOpen(open);
    },
    strategy: "fixed",
    whileElementsMounted: autoUpdate,
    placement: "bottom",
    middleware: [
      offset(ARROW_HEIGHT + GAP),
      flip({
        padding: 8,
        boundary: editor.view.dom,
      }),
      shift({
        padding: 5,
      }),
      arrow({
        element: arrowRef,
        padding: 8,
      }),
      hide({
        strategy: "referenceHidden",
        padding: 0,
      }),
    ],
  });

  const { isMounted, status } = useTransitionStatus(context, {
    duration: 250,
  });

  const dismiss = useDismiss(context);
  const { getReferenceProps, getFloatingProps } = useInteractions([dismiss]);

  const updateReference = () => {
    if (!shouldShow(floating)) return;

    setReference({
      contextElement: editor.view.dom.firstChild as HTMLElement,
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        const { ranges } = editor.state.selection;
        const from = Math.min(...ranges.map((range) => range.$from.pos));
        const to = Math.max(...ranges.map((range) => range.$to.pos));

        if (isNodeSelection(editor.state.selection)) {
          const node = editor.view.nodeDOM(from) as HTMLElement;

          if (node) {
            return node.getBoundingClientRect();
          }
        }
        return posToDOMRect(editor.view, from, to);
      },
    });
  };

  let finalFloatingStyles = {
    ...floatingStyles,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = () => setOpen(shouldShow(floating));
    editor.on("selectionUpdate", onChange);
    editor.on("blur", onChange);
    editor.on("selectionUpdate", updateReference);

    return () => {
      editor.off("selectionUpdate", onChange);
      editor.off("blur", onChange);
      editor.off("selectionUpdate", updateReference);
    };
  });

  console.log(status);

  return (
    <>
      {isMounted && (
        <FloatingPortal>
          <div
            id="floating-wrapper"
            data-scrolling={scrolling}
            ref={setFloating}
            style={finalFloatingStyles}
            data-status={status}
            {...getFloatingProps()}
          >
            <div id="floating" data-status={status} data-placement={placement}>
              {children}
              <FloatingArrow
                ref={arrowRef}
                context={context}
                width={ARROW_WIDTH}
                height={ARROW_HEIGHT}
              ></FloatingArrow>
            </div>
          </div>
        </FloatingPortal>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

```scss
#floating {
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
}
#floating[data-status="open"],
#floating[data-status="close"] {
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}
#floating[data-status="initial"],
#floating[data-status="close"] {
  opacity: 0;
}
#floating[data-status="initial"][data-placement^="top"],
#floating[data-status="close"][data-placement^="top"] {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
#floating[data-status="initial"][data-placement^="bottom"],
#floating[data-status="close"][data-placement^="bottom"] {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
#floating[data-status="initial"][data-placement^="left"],
#floating[data-status="close"][data-placement^="left"] {
  transform: translateX(5px);
}
#floating[data-status="initial"][data-placement^="right"],
#floating[data-status="close"][data-placement^="right"] {
  transform: translateX(-5px);
}

#floating-wrapper[data-status="open"][data-scrolling="false"] {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}

#floating-wrapper[data-status="close"][data-scrolling="false"] {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}

.Editor {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is the working example (select some text and scroll down):

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/controlled-bubble-menu-framer-latest-on-off-forked-3kfydk?file=%2Fsrc%2Fbubble-menu.tsx%3A44%2C51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is playing a little with internal APIs (that aren't typed correctly as a result, so there's some fudge there), but you could modify the `autoUpdate` behaviour passed to `whileElementsMounted` by calling it with a modified (wrapped) `update()` function.

That function will detect scroll events via the undocumented first argument that is passed to it that indicates the event that triggers the auto-update. If the position is being updated in response to a scroll it will set the attribute that disables the transition. Otherwise, it will remove the attribute.

This is experimental at best. You can remove the previous scroll detection. `scrollend` does not do what you think it does, this is related to when the scroll reaches the end of a container. However, keep the CSS targeting `data-scrolling`.

[Here it is in codeasandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/controlled-bubble-menu-framer-latest-on-off-forked-m8kq4s?file=%2Fsrc%2Fbubble-menu.tsx%3A92%2C26&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj920007356hkjzhy8mm%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910003356h78a8sysx%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910004356hse8rc045%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910006356h9wwk5anm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrloxj910003356h78a8sysx%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910003356h78a8sysx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrlp3o0c005q356hxtcchu5p%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A30%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A39%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A30%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A39%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles.scss%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrmbqrzf0002356gzkmi5emp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A92%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A26%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A92%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A26%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fbubble-menu.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrmbqrzf0002356gzkmi5emp%2522%257D%252C%2522clrloxj910006356h9wwk5anm%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910005356hm14864ky%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910006356h9wwk5anm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910005356hm14864ky%2522%257D%252C%2522clrloxj910004356hse8rc045%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrloxj910004356hse8rc045%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```
import {
  useFloating,
  autoUpdate,
  offset,
  flip,
  shift,
  useClick,
  FloatingFocusManager,
  useTransitionStyles,
  FloatingPortal,
  FloatingArrow,
  useTransitionStatus,
  hide,
  inline,
  useDismiss,
  useInteractions,
} from "@floating-ui/react";
import { arrow } from "@floating-ui/react";

import { Editor, isNodeSelection, posToDOMRect } from "@tiptap/core";
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { AnimatePresence, easeIn, motion } from "framer-motion";
import * as Portal from "@radix-ui/react-portal";
import { useCallback } from "react";

const ARROW_WIDTH = 16;
const ARROW_HEIGHT = 8;
const GAP = 8;

type Props = {
  editor: Editor;
  open: boolean;
  setOpen?: any;
  children: ReactNode;
};

// Adapted from https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/2305#issuecomment-1020665146
export const BubbleMenu = ({ editor, children }: Props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  // This function determines whether menu should be shown or not
  const shouldShow = (floating) => {
    // selection not empty?
    let notEmpty = !editor.state.selection.empty;
    if (notEmpty && !editor.isFocused) {
      // We want to hide menu when editor loses focus. The only exception is when
      // Floating element has this focus
      const menuFocused = floating?.contains(document.activeElement);
      if (menuFocused) return true;
      return false;
    }

    return notEmpty;
  };

  const arrowRef = useRef(null);
  const {
    floatingStyles,
    refs: { floating: floatingRef, setReference, setFloating },
    elements: { floating },
    context,
    placement,
  } = useFloating({
    open,

    onOpenChange: (open, event, reason) => {
      setOpen(open);
    },
    strategy: "fixed",
    whileElementsMounted: useCallback((ref, floating, update) => {
      return autoUpdate(ref, floating, ((e: Event | undefined | string) => {
        if ((e as Event)?.type === "scroll") {
          floatingRef.current?.setAttribute("data-scrolling", "true");

          update(e);
          return;
        }

        floatingRef.current?.setAttribute("data-scrolling", "false");

        update(e);
      }) as () => void);
    }, []),
    placement: "bottom",
    middleware: [
      offset(ARROW_HEIGHT + GAP),
      flip({
        padding: 8,
        boundary: editor.view.dom,
      }),
      shift({
        padding: 5,
      }),
      arrow({
        element: arrowRef,
        padding: 8,
      }),
      hide({
        strategy: "referenceHidden",
        padding: 0,
      }),
    ],
  });

  const { isMounted, status } = useTransitionStatus(context, {
    duration: 250,
  });

  const dismiss = useDismiss(context);
  const { getReferenceProps, getFloatingProps } = useInteractions([dismiss]);

  const updateReference = () => {
    if (!shouldShow(floating)) return;

    setReference({
      contextElement: editor.view.dom.firstChild as HTMLElement,
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        const { ranges } = editor.state.selection;
        const from = Math.min(...ranges.map((range) => range.$from.pos));
        const to = Math.max(...ranges.map((range) => range.$to.pos));

        if (isNodeSelection(editor.state.selection)) {
          const node = editor.view.nodeDOM(from) as HTMLElement;

          if (node) {
            return node.getBoundingClientRect();
          }
        }
        return posToDOMRect(editor.view, from, to);
      },
    });
  };

  let finalFloatingStyles = {
    ...floatingStyles,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = () => setOpen(shouldShow(floating));
    editor.on("selectionUpdate", onChange);
    editor.on("blur", onChange);
    editor.on("selectionUpdate", updateReference);

    return () => {
      editor.off("selectionUpdate", onChange);
      editor.off("blur", onChange);
      editor.off("selectionUpdate", updateReference);
    };
  });

  console.log(status);

  return (
    <>
      {isMounted && (
        <FloatingPortal>
          <div
            id="floating-wrapper"
            data-scrolling={false}
            ref={setFloating}
            style={finalFloatingStyles}
            data-status={status}
            {...getFloatingProps()}
          >
            <div id="floating" data-status={status} data-placement={placement}>
              {children}
              <FloatingArrow
                ref={arrowRef}
                context={context}
                width={ARROW_WIDTH}
                height={ARROW_HEIGHT}
              ></FloatingArrow>
            </div>
          </div>
        </FloatingPortal>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: But then when changing the size of selection, there is no animation to move the menu to the center of selection - it moves immidiately.

Comment: I also added `scrolling` state to detect when window is scrolling (for now I skipped the editor scrolling) and I added `data-scrolling` attribute and add animation only if its true, but even that it still animates on scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited the answer for a different approach. The requirement to have it animate when the selection changes whilst avoiding scroll means we need to detect scroll events. But it cant be done with `scrollend`.

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea that its possible to capture `event` in such a way. Does this trick has a name so that I could learn more?

Comment: No. TBH this is a bit hacky. I worked it out from the internals of floating UI. The original `autoUpdate` function registers some handlers for events that might trigger the anchor element to move. When passed to `whileElementsMounted`, it sets up those handlers on mount. So resizing window, scroll, amongst others. Internally, it calls `update()` on these events. What I have done here is look for when it calls `update()` in response to a scroll event, and use that as an opportunity to apply the data attribute. If its called because of another event, it removes the data attribute.

Comment: You won't find this in the docs since there seems to be no native way of achieving this easily via the first-class APIs. You can pass something to disable the detection of scroll events all together ( https://floating-ui.com/docs/autoupdate#ancestorscroll), but you need to still have it call update on scroll (just add this extra attribute to also disable the animation), so that doesn't really work as an option.

Comment: I have another issue with context menu buid with `floating-ui` library. For the menu from this question, I force it stay in place when scrolling usign `contextElement` (first child of scrolled area) on `setReference` method. However, for some reason it does not work for context menu. The questions is here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77854496/position-issue-with-context-menu-inside-scrolled-area-floating-ui) if you are interested :)